# Webflux mongo save multiple models

Tags: spring, mongodb, reactive, project-reactor, spring-webflux

In my application I have servers and users, each user can have multiple servers. The servers list in `User` is a `@DBref`:

```
@DBRef
private List<Server> servers;
```

In the controller where I want to create a server I first create and save the server, after that I add the server to the server list in user and save the user:

```
@PostMapping
public Mono create(@Valid @RequestBody Server server, Mono<Authentication> authentication) {
    return this.serverRepository.save(server) // This works, the server is saved.
            .and(authentication.map(value -> {
                User user = (User) value.getDetails();
                System.out.println(user); // This works, so this function is called.
                if (user.getServers() == null) {
                    // Create empty list so .add can be used.
                    user.setServers(new ArrayList<>());
                }
                user.getServers().add(server);
                return userRepository.save(user); // Isn't working, in the UserCascadeSaveMongoEventListener I don't see it.
            }));
}
```

I think the way I use `.and()` isn't right.

To save the relation I have the `UserCascadeSaveMongoEventListener`:

```
public class UserCascadeSaveMongoEventListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<Object> {

    @Autowired
    private MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    @Override
    public void onBeforeConvert(BeforeConvertEvent<Object> event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        System.out.println(source); // On server create only the Server is shown, User is not shown.
        if ((source instanceof User) && (((User) source).getServers() != null)) {
            mongoOperations.save(((User) source).getServers());
        }
    }
}
```

But this class doesn't matter at the moment because the user isn't save at all.

The repositories used are all normal ReactiveCrudRepositories.

What is the right way to reactively call multiple repositories with multiple Mono's?

Comment: I hope you have registered this listener. Have you?

Comment: Yes, I left comments in the listener what is working.

Comment: So control comes to onBeforeConveret for the first save call but not for the second. is that correct?

Comment: @pvpkiran Yes the server is saved but the user not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `save` call does not actually save, it's setting up a reactive pipeline that you can use to save. The operation is only performed when something subscribes to it:

```
Mono<User> savedUser = userRepository.save(user);
```

So you should compose the various bits in your controller method and make sure that no reactive type is left hanging alone.

You could have seen that by adding a `log()` operator after the save operation - nothing subscribes to it so the operation is not performed.

Your code should look like (that's if you want to return the created user as a response; if you don't want to return anything, you can add a final `then()` operator right at the end and make your controller method return a `Mono<Void>` that signals when the operation is done):

```
@PostMapping
public Mono<User> create(@Valid @RequestBody Server server, Mono<Authentication> authentication) {
    return this.serverRepository.save(server) // This works, the server is saved.
            .then(authentication.flatMap(value -> {
                User user = (User) value.getDetails();
                System.out.println(user); // This works, so this function is called.
                if (user.getServers() == null) {
                    // Create empty list so .add can be used.
                    user.setServers(new ArrayList<>());
                }
                user.getServers().add(server);
                return userRepository.save(user);
            }));
}
```

Comment: I didn't saw that... But it still doesn't work. Still exactly the same.

Comment: the user isn't saved at all? or the user/server relationship is missing?

Comment: I'm sorry I was a little bit to fast, I will test it again.

Comment: It is reaching the UserCascadeSaveMongoEventListener! But it can't execute the `mongoOperations.save(((User) source).getServers());` because of `org.bson.Document cannot be cast to com.mongodb.BasicDBList`